# Convert deprecated sql to correct one

Tags: sql-server, deprecated

Is there some script available whihc can rewrite the deprecated sql syntax to proper one to be specific

```
select A.* from db.table1 as A , db.table2 B , db1.table3 C
where A.column1=B.columnx and B.columnx=c.column3 and B.Column6 in ('A','B','C')
and C.column9='%test%'
```

to

```
Select A.* from db.table1 as A INNER JOIN db.table2 B ON A.column1=B.columnx 
INNER JOIN  db1.table3 C ON  B.columnx=c.column3
 WHERE  B.Column6 in ('A','B','C') and C.column9='%test%'
```

I have more than 10K sql for which i have to parse and rewrite the code with current syntax.

Is there anyone done this before and having something can be shared.

Any pointers/solution will be of great help.

Comment: Where did you hear that the syntax above is deprecated?

Comment: Are you using MSSQL ? I can see the need to update your syntax if you're upgrading to a newer SQL Server.

Comment: Yes I am using mssql and the syntax is deprecated https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: More than 10,000 sql queries with implicit joins? Seems like you're in for a lot of work... I'd Imagine that at least some of the queries you have does not have joins at all... Are these queries saved as stored procedures, functions  and views, or are they saved as files? Perhaps they are inline queries in an outside program? we need more details...

Comment: These are stored as .SQL files in an UNIX environment and extracted using an ETL tool. The ETL tool takes the sql file extracts and places the data into a file. I wanted to pass this sql files into a utility and convert the deprecated syntax to correct sytax.